# Azure Devops: MySQL Database Deployment on Machine Group issue ERROR 1045

Tags: mysql, azure-devops

I’m having issues when trying to run a mysql database on the Machine Group task from azure devops pipeline, I see that mysql-client and server are already installed on the agents but when using the default exemple from the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/mysqldb-deployment?view=azure-devops)
this is the basic config I’m using :

```
 steps:
    - task: MysqlDeploymentOnMachineGroup@1
      displayName: 'Deploy Using : InlineSqlTask'
      inputs:
        TaskNameSelector: InlineSqlTask
        SqlInline: |
          CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS alm;
          use alm;
        ServerName: localhost
        SqlUsername: root
        SqlPassword: P2ssw0rd
```

I get an error that returns:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000) Access denied for user ‘root’@‘localhost’ (using password: YES)
```

I’m out of ideas to solve the issue could anyone help me out

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR 1045 (28000) Access denied for user ‘root’@‘localhost’ (using

> password: YES)

The error is a common issue when your MySQL Database password is set abnormally. The issue occurs when you first installed MySQL and try to login with the password.

You can set the root user password after firstly using MySQL.

```
Login as user root with blank password

>mysql -u root

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
```

Then enter the correct username and password to login MySQL.

```
mysql –u username –p
```

You also need to enter the correct host name to avoid error 1045.

```
mysql> mysql -u root -p123 -h <IP> -P 3306
```

To avoid the error, which the importance is to make the username and password as well as hostname is correct.